# C# asp.net datagrid when editing show only date

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Birthadate" DataFormatString="{0:d}" 
                    HeaderText="Gimimo data" SortExpression="Birthadate" />
```

I have formated date, but when i press edit it gives me edti date and time? How to do not show time?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [ApplyFormatInEditMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.applyformatineditmode.aspx) to true in order to push the item formatting into the edit item.

```
<asp:BoundField ApplyFormatInEditMode="true" DataField="Birthadate" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderText="Gimimo data" SortExpression="Birthadate" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this out first use Mouse Click event, whenever you click on this DataGrid grab the value in the selected cell into a string.

```
string selectedValue = "";
```

since it has a space in between 17 and 00 you can write it likes this

```
string finalResult = selectedValue.substring(0,selectedValue.indexOf(" ")-1);
```

then again pass the value in the finalResult to that specific cell.
that's all. you don't need to use DateTime strut in this example.